# Retrieve regex location inside OpenResty Lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

How should I get the part that's matched by a regex location in OpenResty / Nginx Lua module?

For example, I want to use `$1` in Lua in the following case:

```
location ~ ^/example/([0-9]+)/ {
  content_by_lua_block {
    -- What to use for \1 ?
    ngx.say("Code: " .. (ngx.var.1 + 1))
  }
}
```

The expected behavior would be getting `Code: 1235` when visiting `/example/1234/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ngx.var.1` with `ngx.var[1]`

From Lua reference manual:

> The syntax `var.Name` is just syntactic sugar for `var["Name"]`

However, it only works with string keys.

From OpenResty manual:

> Nginx regex group capturing variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and etc, can be read by this interface as well, by writing `ngx.var[1]`, `ngx.var[2]`, `ngx.var[3]`, and etc.